# vector serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, vector

I am trying to binary serialize the data of vector. In this sample below I serialize to a string, and then deserialize back to a vector, but do not get the same data I started with.  Why is this the case?

```
vector<size_t> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);

string s((char*)(&v[0]), 3 * sizeof(size_t));

vector<size_t> w(3);
strncpy((char*)(&w[0]), s.c_str(), 3 * sizeof(size_t));

for (size_t i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i) {
    cout << w[i] << endl;
}
```

I expect to get the output

```
1  
2
3
```

but instead get the output

```
1
0
0
```

(on [gcc-4.5.1](http://ideone.com/bXjuM))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the call to [`strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy). From the linked page:

> If the length of *src* is less than *n*, strncpy() pads the remainder of dest with null bytes.

So, after the first `0` byte in the serialized data is found the remainder of `w`'s data array is padded with `0`s.

To fix this, use a `for` loop, or `std::copy`

```
std::copy( &s[0], 
           &s[0] + v.size() * sizeof(size_t), 
           reinterpret_cast<char *>(w.data()) );
```

---

IMO, instead of using `std::string` as a buffer, just use a `char` array to hold the serialized data.

[Example](http://ideone.com/7H8dy) on ideone

Comment: Good catch on the `strncpy`, I never knew about that "feature" and was baffled as to why his code didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Why std::copy is better than memcpy?

Comment: Since you're copying an array of integers both will work the same. But let's say the vector contained an object that managed some resource. memcpy would perform a bitwise copy of the object, which is most likely not the way you want it copied. std::copy, on the other hand, will invoke the assignment operator ensuring the object is copied correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`strncpy` is a giant pile of fail. It will terminate early on your input because the `size_t` have some zero bytes, which it interprets as the NULL terminator, leaving them as default-constructed 0. If you ran this test on a BE machine, all would be 0. Use `std::copy`.

Answer (score -1):

To serialize this vector into a string, You first want to convert each of the elements of of this vector from an int into a string containing the same the ascii representation of that number, this operation can be called serialization of an int to string.

So for example, assuming an integer is 10 digits we can

```
// create temporary string to hold each element
char intAsString[10 + 1];
```

then convert the integer to a string

```
sprintf(intAsString, "%d", v[0]);
```

or

```
itoa( v[0], intAsString, 10 /*decimal number*/ );
```

You can also make use of the ostringstream and the << operator

if you look at the memory contents of intAsString and v[0], they are very different, the first contains the ascii letters that represent the value of v[0] in the decimal number system(base 10) while v[0] contains the binary representation of the number(because that's how computers store numbers).

Comment: It seems clear to me he wants binary serialization, not text serialization.  Also, `sprintf` and `itoa` in C++ code?

Comment: well he made a string to hold the output so that's why I assumed he wants text serialization.
Thanks for the comment though :)

Comment: No, the string is copied to a vector, and the vector holds the output.  The string is merely a binary buffer.

Answer (score -1):

The safest way would be to just loop through the vector and store the values individually into a char array of size 3*sizeof(size_t). That way you don't have a dependency on the internal structure of the vector class implementation.

Comment: vector and string are both guaranteed to be contiguous and without padding in C++11, so that's a non-issue.